# Add additional space when fullstop were press C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox and I want to add a space in between every time I press "."(fullstop).

It should automatically add/insert a space(without pressing the spacebar) after I press fullstop.

Comment: Is this win forms? Can this be done on submit of the form instead of everytime the full stop is pressed? It would stop multiple calls to the server when you can do it all in one go

Comment: Yup, its WindowsFormsApplication in Visual Studio

Comment: Okay, can this be done on submit of the form?

Comment: I'm exactly not sure lol, Im still new to this(a beginner)

Comment: Okay, do you have a button which you press which goes into your code with the content of the richtextbox? I'll try to help :)

Comment: Oh , I dont have any button. Just a richtextbox and a form only

Comment: Okay, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok , my goal is . When every time i press the fullstop "." key. It automatically add an extra space (without even pressing the spacebar) in the richtextbox.

Comment: I understand that, but I believe the best solution would be to do this when you submit the contents of your richtextbox to the server. For example, if a user writes a full stop in their text box and then it adds a space, they may go back and delete it. This could be an issue for you and it sounds like it will be. It's also not efficient as you have to keep doing a job over and over again when you can just do it once at the end. If you still want to only do it when you press a full stop you can and I'll help. I'm just giving you my 2 pence worth(or after the referendum about -20p)

Comment: it's okay :) . I think I have figured out my problem. Thanks again :)

Comment: Okay, how have you got the solution?

Comment: Hi, sry for the long reply ya . the answer is  If(e.KeyChar == '.')
{
rtxt.Text += " ";}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will add a space after a **Fullstop(.)** has been pressed. You need to use the [**`KeyUp`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx) Event.

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod)
        richTextBox1.Text += " ";
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
}
```

Comment: It works , many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to handle richTextBox.OnKeyUp event so that if the key that is pressed is the fullstop then append your text with the space.

```
private void RichtextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Determine whether the key entered is the period key. Append a space to the textbox if it is.
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod)
    {
        RichTextBox1.Text += " ";
    }
}
```

Obviously you will have to create this event for your own richTextBox rather than my example of "RichTextBox1"

Comment: thanks you for the answers!!! :))))))

Comment: If a post is helpful please remember to upvote